# Xamarin.Forms HybridWebView zoom (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, zooming

I created a `WebViewPage` class that inherits from `HybridWebView`
Now I need to implement the zoom but I can not find the string that allows to do

**code:**

```
public class WebViewPage : HybridWebView
    {
           ...code
    }
     protected override void OnStart()
            {
                var webView = Container.GetInstance<WebViewPage>();
                webView.LoadFromContent("index.html");
    ...code
    }
```

how I enable pinch to `zoom`?

Comment: Is `HybridWebView` the one from the Xamarin custom renderer sample?

Comment: use that from github https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/HybridWebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify the source and set the appropriate WebKit zoom settings.

re: [setBuiltInZoomControls](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean))

In the [`HybridWebViewRenderer.cs`](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/63d0187047bf814748f715e85e0a335784fe93c2/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.Droid/Controls/HybridWebView/HybridWebViewRenderer.cs#L74) you need to turn on `BuiltInZoomControls`
 and turn the visual zoom controls (`DisplayZoomControls`) off (if not desired).

```
webView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
webView.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = false;
```

Comment: but to make this change is it necessary to recompile the entire library?

Comment: @luk4 yes, the andriod library needs mod'ed to do what you need.